# Is it possible to follow up on a post you've flagged?

Tags: support, flagging

That's basically it. I flagged my first post today and I wanted to see what happened to it to make sure I had used a flag correctly. Is there anyway of finding that post again? (I can't remember the question it was on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your profile you can see "helpful flags". The number of helpful (and rejected) flags for you can hence be seen here

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/7433

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for